# Entity Framework with Fluent Mapping - Composite Primary Key, One to many

Tags: entity-framework

I have the following code. I want to build a fluent mapping so that my Image has a non-nullable composite primary key made up of Defect_Id and Asset_Id. How do I achieve this? I'm getting the error **The property 'Defect' cannot be used as a key property on the entity 'TSIR.Core.Domain.Image' because the property type is not a valid key type. Only scalar types, string and byte[] are supported key types.**

```
public class Image
{
    public Defect Defect { get; set; }
    public int AssetId { get; set; }
}

public class Defect
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    private ICollection<Image> _images;

    public ICollection<Image> Images
    {
        get => _images ?? (_images = new Collection<Image>());
        set => _images = value;
    }
}

public ImageConfiguration()
{
    ToTable("Images").HasKey(entity => new
    {
        Defect = entity.Defect,
        entity.AssetId
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My advice would be to stick more to the [entity framework code first conventions](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/code-first-conventions.aspx). Only deviate from them if you really need to (and can convince your project leader that it the deviations make your classes more comprehensible, better testable, better maintainable, etc)

Keep your entity classes simple POCOs, don't add fields. Let entity framework decide what type the "set" items should be.

So apparently every `Defect` has zero or more `Images`, every `Asset` also has zero or more `Images`, every `Image` belongs to exactly one `Defect` and one `Assert`, namely the `Defect` and `Asset` with the foreign keys this `Image` has.

If you created simple one-to-many relations, then there wouldn't be any problem.

```
Defect Id 1
Asset Id 3

// Traditional one-to-many: allows several images with same [Defect, Assert]
Image Id 10 with DefectId 1 and AssetId 3
Image Id 11 with DefectId 1 and AssetId 3
Image Id 12 with DefectId 1 and AssetId 3
```

The problem arises, because you want to use these foreign keys as primary keys. This is probably to prevent two Images having the same [Defect, Assert].

```
// your composite key allows only one image with this [Defect, Assert]
Image Id [1, 3] with DefectId 1 and AssetId 3
// no other Image for this Defect 1 and Asset 3 possible
```

If and only if your model represents a reality where it is impossible to have several images with the same [Defect, Asset], only then your solution will be better.

```
class Defect
{
    public int Id {set; set;}
    ... // other properties

    // every Defect has zero or more Images
    public virtual ICollection<Image> Images {get; set;}
}
class Asset
{
    public int Id {set; set;}
    ... // other properties

    // every Asset has zero or more Images
    public virtual ICollection<Image> Images {get; set;}
}

class Image
{
    // composite primary key: [DefectId, AssetId]
    // every Image belongs to exactly one Defect, using foreign key
    public int DefectId {get; set;}
    public virtual Defect Defect {get; set;}

    // every Image belongs to exactly one Asset, using foreign key
    public int AssetId {get; set;}
    public virtual Asset Asset {get; set;}
}
```

> In entity framework the columns of your tables are represented by non-virtual properties, the virtual properties represent the relations between your tables (one-to-many, many-to-many, ...)

In your case: don't forget your foreign keys.

In OnModelCreating:

```
var imageEntity = modelBuilder.Entity<Image>();

// every image has composite primary key
imageEntity.HasKey(image => new {image.DefectId, image.AssetId});
```

It might be that this (together with your virtual properties) is enough for entity framework to detect your relations, especially the primary keys and foreign keys. If not, inform entity framework about them:

```
// every image belongs to exactly one Defect, using foreign key
imageEntity.HasRequired(image => image.Defect)
    .WithMany(defect => defect.Images)
    .HasForeignKey(image => image.DefectId,

imageEntity.HasRequired(image => image.Asset)
    .WithMany(asset => assert.Images)
    .HasForeignKey(image => image.AssetId);
```

Comment: Yea the key seemed to be in your last paragraph. I did a composite key.

ToTable("Images").HasKey(entity => new
            {
                entity.DefectId,
                entity.AssetId
            })
                .HasRequired(image => image.Defect)
                .WithMany(g => g.Images)
                .HasForeignKey(s=> s.DefectId);

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you cannot include your Defect object as part of the Key.

Include both int properties for AssetId and DefectId on your Image class. Then in your config use those instead of the Defect object which is what's causing your error.

```
public class Image
{
    public int DefectId { get; set; }
    public Defect Defect { get; set; }
    public int AssetId { get; set; }
}

public class Defect
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    private ICollection<Image> _images;

    public ICollection<Image> Images
    {
        get => _images ?? (_images = new Collection<Image>());
        set => _images = value;
    }
}

public ImageConfiguration()
{
    ToTable("Images").HasKey(entity => new
    {
        entity.DefectId,
        entity.AssetId
    });
}
```